# Getting "Misplaced alignment tab character &" error when trying to use \begin{align*}

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm getting an error when trying to align using `\begin{align*}` from `amsmath`.

This is my code:

```
\begin{align*}  

$[\Gamma(A \otimes B)\Delta, C]             &\cong [\Gamma A B \Delta, C]$,\\
$[\Gamma, A/B]                              &\cong [\Gamma B, A]$, \\
$[\Gamma, A \backslash B]                   &\cong [\Gamma B, A]$, \\
$[\Gamma, A \times B]                       &\cong [\Gamma, A] \times [\Gamma, B]$, \\
$[\Gamma(A + B)\Delta, C]                   &\cong [\Gamma A \Delta C] \times [\Gamma B \Delta, C]$, \\
$[\Gamma I \Delta, C]                       &\cong [\Gamma \Delta, C]$, \\
$[\Gamma, 1]                                &\cong \{*\}$, \\
$[\Gamma 0 \Delta, C]                       &\cong \{*\}$, \\
$[\Gamma, \prod\limits_{x} A(X)]            &\cong [\Gamma, A(X)]x$, \\
$[\Gamma \coprod\limits_{x} A(X) \Delta, C] &\cong [\Gamma A(X) \Delta, C]$.

\end{align*}
```

And those are the errors:

```
Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
Missing $ inserted.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Display math should end with $$.
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma(A \otimes B)\Delta, C] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma, A/B] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma, A \backslash B] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma, A \times B] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma(A + B)\Delta, C] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma I \Delta, C] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma, 1] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma 0 \Delta, C] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $[\Gamma, \prod\limits_{x} A(X)] &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. ...amma \coprod\limits_{x} A(X) \Delta, C] &
Misplaced \cr. \end{align*}
Misplaced \noalign. \end{align*}
Misplaced \noalign. \end{align*}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{align*}
Missing $ inserted. \end{align*}
Display math should end with $$. \end{align*}
```

For clarification, I'm trying to make this part of the code (1)centralized in the page and (2)aligned in the `\cong` symbol:
[image]
Just like this:

[image]

What can I do to fix my code?

Comment: Empty lines are not allowed inside math environments, that's one obvious mistake.

Comment: Also, `align` starts math mode, so all the `$` inside it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to (a) getting rid of the two all-blank lines and (b) omitting all `$` symbols, you may also want to (c) get rid of the busy-looking commas at the end of each line and (d) in the final 2 lines, use `_{X}` instead of `_{x}` and increase the sizes of the enclosing square brackets. Still on the final two lines: Optionally, I would use `\textstyle` rather than the default `\displaystyle` to size the `\prod` and `coprod` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}  
[\Gamma(A \otimes B)\Delta, C]  &\cong [\Gamma A B \Delta, C] \\
[\Gamma, A/B]                   &\cong [\Gamma B, A] \\
[\Gamma, A \backslash B]        &\cong [\Gamma B, A] \\
[\Gamma, A \times B]            &\cong [\Gamma, A] \times [\Gamma, B] \\
[\Gamma(A + B)\Delta, C]        &\cong [\Gamma A \Delta C] \times [\Gamma B \Delta, C] \\
[\Gamma I \Delta, C]            &\cong [\Gamma \Delta, C] \\
[\Gamma, 1]                     &\cong \{*\} \\
[\Gamma 0 \Delta, C]            &\cong \{*\} \\
\Bigl[\Gamma,\prod_{X}A(X)\Bigr]&\cong [\Gamma, A(X)]x \\
\Bigl[\Gamma\coprod_{X}A(X) 
    \Delta,C\Bigr]              &\cong [\Gamma A(X) \Delta, C]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```